# Text borders in svg and d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a text border but the results aren't what I expected. Is there a way to make it so that text borders remain constant when zooming in and out? For example, in this jsfiddle when I zoom in and out it leaves a shadow from the blue and the white stroke is noticeable even though the background is white.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F3PhZ/1/

and the relevant code:

```
canvas.append("text")
      .text("Jennifer Lawrence")
      .attr("font-family", "Arial")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("font-size", "16px")
      .attr("x", 100)
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .attr("stroke", "white")
      .attr("stroke-width", ".2px");
```

The effect I want is based off of:
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/02/20/movies/among-the-oscar-contenders-a-host-of-connections.html so that when there are lines of different colors the text that overlaps the line will be more noticeable because of the white border and the text that doesn't overlap looks normal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .attr("vector-effect", "non-scaling-stroke") It works on Opera and Webkit and has recently been fixed on Firefox to work properly on text - I think you'll need Firefox 24.

vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" is not however supported by IE so you'd have to code something in javascript that fixed up the stroke-width inversely as you zoomed if you wanted to support IE9 or IE10.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue where the vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke works fine on all the other browsers except IE. I am in a condition that i cannot fix this using JS. Please suggest me some solution using CSS.

Comment: I suggest you ask your own question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I cannot ask the same question again on SO. My problem is the same. I've applied `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` to a path element and it's not working in IE. Stroke width of path element is much thicker.